# Absolute values

Tags: calculus

Determine how close $x$ has to be from $a$ ($a$ being a fixed positive real number) for the following inequality $|x^{\frac{3}{
2}} - a^{\frac{3}{2}}| \lt \varepsilon$ to be true.

with $\varepsilon \gt 0$

I don't know how to go with this. Help please?

Comment: $(x^3-a^3)=(x^\frac32+a^\frac32)(x^\frac34+a^\frac34)(x^\frac34-a^\frac34)$, right?

Comment: By the way, edited, it was actually $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: My comment was a hint. It helps to somehow involve $x-a$, like $x^3-a^3=(x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solve the inequality: since $a$ and $\epsilon$ are fixed:
$$-\epsilon + a^{\frac{3}{2}} <x^{\frac{3}{2}} < \epsilon + a^{\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$(\max(0,-\epsilon + a^{\frac{3}{2}}))^{\frac{2}{3}} -a < x-a < (\epsilon + a^{\frac{3}{2}})^{\frac{2}{3}} - a$$
Let $x=a-(\max(0,-\epsilon + a^{\frac{3}{2}}))^{\frac{2}{3}}$, $y=(\epsilon + a^{\frac{3}{2}})^{\frac{2}{3}} - a$

Notice that both $x$ and $y$ are positive, we could take $\delta = \min(x,y)$, and we have:

$|x^{\frac{3}{2}}-a^{\frac{3}{2}}| < \epsilon$, whenever $|x-a| < \delta$